# Editing Geoman map cursor tooltip

Tags: javascript, reactjs, leaflet-geoman

In my React app, I'd like to edit the text displayed in the cursor tool-tip when using a Geoman tool (and providing texts for different languages like Geoman does). Is there any built-in way to do this or should I use a querySelector ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can overwritte the tooltips with your [custom translation](https://github.com/geoman-io/leaflet-geoman#customize-language):

```
const customTranslation = {
  tooltips: {
    placeMarker: 'Custom Marker Translation',
  },
};

map.pm.setLang('customName', customTranslation, 'en');
```